# Type two objects with the same type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two objects, each one representing translations into a specific language.

Is there a way to type my objects, so they have the same types (ideally without defining one extra type that includes the union of all keys).

My ultimate goal is that if I add one key into one object, typescript will notify me that I need to add that new key into the other object.

```
const messages_gr = {
  'login.title': 'Είσοδος',
};

const messages_en = {
  'login.title': 'Login',
};
```

Comment: You can choose one object to act as the exemplar (for example, `messages_gr`), then create a type using `typeof`: `type Message = typeof messages_gr`. Then, mark all objects as `Message` (for example, `const messages_en: Message = { ... }`).

Comment: @superhawk610 right, even without intermediate type if there're only two objects https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcyQfTQJxgXhgG8AoGGAcgBsQ0BLMAOijqioQoC5LBU4EHrgQMPAgfuBALcBDAQ8AUANGUo16TAGYgQXXoNETpJAL4BuEiVCRYiZOiwIw3KAE8ADghCL4SVBgjY8hUuWq0GZlZ2NQoAGQCwbX0gA

Comment: Thank you both! This is a solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a class Message and make different objects of the message like so:

```
class Message {
  constructor(loginTitle) {
    this.loginTitle = loginTitle;
  }
}

// Create objects of class
const messages_gr = new Message("Είσοδος");
const messages_en = new Message("Login");
```

This way you won't have to create new objects like that. Hopefully, this will solve your problem!